# Power BI Report Server Scheduled Refresh

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I have developed a dashboard using Power BI (Import Mode). We scheduled it for refresh and after the refresh runs, the dashboard gets updated in the web portal. But, if I download it and open it in the Power BI Desktop, the data does not refresh without again clicking on refresh in the Power BI Desktop too. The problem is we do not want to provide the end user the access to the database, and hence, when the user clicks on refresh in the Power BI Desktop, it asks for credentials and does not refresh.

Can someone please suggest a way around? Or are there any APIs to achieve this? I read online that data refresh can be achieved using APIs in Power BI Service. I was hoping to know if there are any for on-premises version? We are using Power BI Report Server January 2019.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Users may not see download option as they are not assigned as admin role to report server. Best bet is to see updated reports on server rather download the local copy.

API refresh do the same as schedule refresh on report server.

[API Documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/PBIRS/2.0)

Comment: The users see the download option in the report server, just dont see the updated report when they download it. I want them to be able to see the latest report. Do the APIs solve this problem or they will also just refresh the report on the server and no change to the downloaded report? I would think that it is incorrect behaviour if the downloaded report is not an updated one, even after the scheduled refresh has run and beats the purpose of refresh. Please correct me if I am wrong.